# Inserting some text to exact location of an existing text file

Tags: c#, file

I'm trying to insert Some text in exact location on existing file. 
First method I've applied-
Which does not effect anything??

```
       string newData;
       string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("lal.txt");
       int indx = data.IndexOf("1");
       if (data.Contains("1"))
       {
           MessageBox.Show(indx.ToString());
           newData=data.Insert(indx+1, "ooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
           File.WriteAllText("lal.txt",data);

       }
```

Another Method I'm using --This method completely erases all contents or creates no content ???

```
 string newData;
        string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("lal.txt");
       int indx = data.IndexOf("1");
       if (data.Contains("1"))
       {
           MessageBox.Show(indx.ToString());
           newData=data.Insert(indx+1, "ooooooooooooooooooooooooo");

           var f = new StreamWriter(File.Create("ll1.txt"));
           f.Write(newData);
           //data.Insert(indx, "OIasasas");
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First snippet has error: changed string is in newData variable, but you wrote unchanged string to file.

2nd snippet has another error: you write proper string, but do not close file stream, so changes may not be made.

This should work

```
string data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("lal.txt");
int indx = data.IndexOf("1");
if (indx != -1)
{
    var newData = data.Insert(indx + 1, "ooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
    File.WriteAllText("lal.txt", newData);
}
```